# Digital Logic Reset

Tags: digital-logic, counter, reset

Question Too broad apparently.

Comment: Any time you want to count something, you are talking about sequential logic, in which the current state depends on the previous history, not just the current input values. The first problem is to define exactly what an "attempt" is in terms of the logic. Do you have a pushbutton that you press to identify an attempt?

Comment: An 'attempt' would be the input K1, K2, K3 changing to 0 or 1, those are button inputs using the program Logisim http://i.imgur.com/l3QutNV.png

Comment: For your lock circuit, an attempt should be when the user finally wants to test to see if the input combination is correct.  It should not be the fact that the combination switches (k1,k2,k3) were changed.

Comment: what type of gates/ICs are you allowed to use?  (I know the original lock was limited to ANDs, ORs, and NOTs).

Comment: Any of them can be used for this problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said in the comments to the question, you're going to have to have a counter to indicate when the two matches (Kn and In, and Xn and a counter match or mismatch.

If you're allowed to, use an octal counter like [the CD4022](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC14022B-D.PDF).  Using the same logic as above, implement a 3 to 8 decoders on the three X1, X2, and X3 bits.  Match up the eight outputs of the decoder with the eight outputs of the counter, and output a 1 if the values *don't* match (so you'll need a NOT).  AND that with the output of the original matching circuit AND the output of a button (1 if pressed).  So you have a 1 if Kn and In match, and the Xn and counter *mismatch*, and the button is pressed. You are done with a good result.

Otherwise, if the output of the X1 ... X3 decoder matches the output of the the counter, stop (perhaps setting an SR flipflop made up of two AND and NOT gates forming two NAND's).  If Xn and the counter don't match, and the Kn doesn't match In, increment the counter as the button is released (falling edge).

Comment: The octal counter cannot be used, however, I understand what you are saying and thanks for the reply. Learnt much from this and will try to implement

Comment: @fark It's not that difficult to make a binary counter from D-type flip-flops such [this one](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig56.php).  You just need three instead four since you are counting up to 7, not 15.  You would need to add a 3-8 decoder like you did before.  In turn you can make the [D-flip-flops from ordinary gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Master.E2.80.93slave_edge-triggered_D_flip-flop).

Comment: Does it need to be a master-slave D flip-flop or is this sufficient? http://i.imgur.com/k33Jg6t.png

Comment: @fark yes, I believe that will work.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/9BPKTz6.png Is that where you are trying to come from? I've only done the bottom input for an example and left the other AND outputs to nothing. So would I need a D latch for all those outputs then OR them together and NOR the last output?

Comment: @fark The bottom you have is one flip-flop.  Think of each of them as a block.  You need three, with the inputs and outputs wired up as shown in the [binary counter](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Digital/dig56.php) but only the first three blocks.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. Man I should really move onto another problem but I really want to finish this haha.